# GoLang GORM Cyclical Binary Tree

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to model a database in GoLang (go 1.16) using GORM (gorm.io/gorm v1.21.9).

Part of my schema includes table A with 2 optional foreign keys, in practice only 1 will be used for each record. Table B contains 2 references to table A, like a binary tree. Table C is a leaf node.

[image: ERD]
Figure 1. Entity Relationship Diagram

[image: Example Usage]
Figure 2. Example Usage

I have the GORM code set up as shown below.

```
type A struct {
    ID   string
    BID  *string
    B    *B
    CID  *string
    C    *C
}

type B struct {
    ID       string
    LeftAID  string
    LeftA    A
    RightAID string
    RightA   A
}

type C struct {
    ID string
}
```

When I load the application with sample data, table B always has null values for it's foreign keys.

[image: Table B Data]

However, Table A has a value for table_b_id for every record (should be null when table_c_id exists).

[image: Table A Data]

I'm guessing that, since table A has a foreign key to table B, it's using that association in all cases, instead of picking up the right_a_id and left_a_id associations. Is there a GORM annotation that will fix this, or is this a limitation inherent to GORM?

Please note that I have removed the unrelated schema information and used abstracted table/column names.

Comment: Did you declared the gorm struct tags for describing ?

Comment: No, I'm using the defaults, what are the correct struct tags for this pattern?

Comment: take a look at the documentation of GORM, https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking through the doc prior to posting this and since. I have not found anything that works. I'm hoping someone on SO will have seen this before and know a set of tags that will work for this pattern. If I can't find an answer on here I will have to modify my schema.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should uses
`Self-Referential Has One`
[Self-Referential Has One](https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html#Self-Referential-Has-One)
like follow

```
type A struct {
    ID   string
    LeftID  *string
    LeftA    *A `gorm:"foreignkey:LeftID"`
    RightID *string
    RightA    *A `gorm:"foreignkey:RightID"`
    LeafID *string
    LeafA    *A `gorm:"foreignkey:LeafID"`
}
```

test code:

```
func main() {
    db := config.CreateMysql()
    db.AutoMigrate(&A{})
    a1 := A{ID: "a1"}
    a2 := A{ID: "a2"}
    a3 := A{ID: "a3"}
    a4 := A{ID: "a4"}
    a5 := A{ID: "a5"}

    a1.LeftA = &a2
    a1.RightA = &a3

    a4.LeafA = &a5

    db.Create(&a1)
    db.Create(&a4)
}
```

in db like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I have seen that structure in the docs and I wish I could use it. Unfortunately some of my other requirements necessitate using 2 separate tables, which is where the problem arises. I'm new to gorm and I wasn't able to find any doc with the correct tags to make my schema work.